# Array formula filled down right instead of 1x \cell

Tags: google-sheets

J need help to replace those formulas with filled down right array formula .
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(--IF(MMULT(--(ROW(F$17:F18)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(F$17:F18))),--IF(E$17:E18=N19,F$17:F18,0))

=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(--IF(OFFSET(E$17,,,V19+1)=N19,1,0),OFFSET(F$17,,,V19+1),OFFSET(H$17,,,V19+1))-SUMIF(N$18:N18,N19,Z$18:Z18)), 1, 1)

=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA((SUMIF(N$18:N19,N19,O$18:O19)-SUMPRODUCT(--IF(OFFSET(E$17,,,V19+1)=N19,1,0),OFFSET(F$17,,,V19+1)))*OFFSET(H$17,V19,,,)), 1, 1)

=IF(SUMIF(N$18:N19,N19,O$18:O19)>SUM(E$18:E19,N19,F$18:F19),MAX(SUMIF(E$18:E19,N19,G$18:G19)-SUMIF(N$18:N18,N19,P$18:P18),0),Y19)

Regards

Update,
Below my sheet link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N-cFefzlKE0Ccn-Pu67HwnC77n6QxZCB5OOf6lsAS5I/edit?usp=sharing

i need to replace formulas in columen V,W,X,Y,Z in FIFO tape TO FILL DOWN on array formula.

Thanks.
eXCEL SHEET LINK

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z7B5KZ3HEPBAj3TCApCy5KGkdNy0G-mmqfEj_SGz4bM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome. Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding any private or confidential information), and ensure that it includes an example of successful outcomes of your problem code.

Comment: sheet link shared, thank you for your support.

Comment: Sorry, made an error in the entry in cell V19. Please re-enter.

Comment: Your have listed four formula and five columns. Would you please explain the purpose/objective for each formula, including the formula in the fifth column.

Comment: neglect column Y

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z7B5KZ3HEPBAj3TCApCy5KGkdNy0G-mmqfEj_SGz4bM/edit?usp=sharing
tHIS LINK FOR EXCEL SHEET

Comment: for column V (This column calculates number of rows it takes to make sure total purchased quantity is greater than cumulative consumption. Calculation starts from row 16. In other words it tells us how many purchase line items in column D we need to add up so their total quantity exceeds cumulative quantity in column J.
To make it more fun this calculation is done considering index (SKU) given in column I.)